# vscode debugging typescript leads to JS files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a service I wrote in typescript with vscode.
Up until now, I did not have any issues debugging, when I ran the debugger, it would debug via the typescript files.

But now when I run the service and debug, it takes me to the javascript compiled files, which makes debugging practically impossible.

This is the debugging configuration I use:

```
{
   "type": "node",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Program",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts",
   "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
   "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "protocol": "inspector",
   "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

I also tried running without `preLaunchTask` & `outFiles` but the result is the same.

Please advise on how can I properly debug the code.